# Accordion not working as expected in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add accordion in my HTML page it is not working at all. I am not sure if I was integrating correct version of js (`jquery-3.6.0.min.js`). Should I import something else? I can't figure it out. This is my code :

index.html

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
```

index.js

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}
});
}
```

Also, I followed this [W3S page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) step by step, but can't find any problem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Answer (score 1):

That very [w3schools - How TO - Collapsibles/Accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) won't work properly, if you don't assign max-height to `<div class="panel">`:

CSS:

```
.panel {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: @bitksi I did assing actually but still not working

Comment: @pattes Do you load the index.js at the bottom of your HTML - before `</body>`?

Comment: yes when ı clicked it I access the file as well

Comment: @pattes: Could you anyhow provide a link to check your code?

Comment: @pattes I rather meant a url

Comment: I found the solution before my accordion function  there was another one Probably that one is not working  therefore, it wont compile the following codes I believe

Comment: Thanks for your help and time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery (like you mentioned), you can use the `.slideToggle` method (https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). Here's an example, which also uses some other handy jQuery methods:

```js
$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Here's a working example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/andyranged/pen/16a51bb5f076bf2348023c000ce7ded0